# why regexec() of C does not match this pattern, but match() of javascript works?

Tags: c, regex

I have this pattern `[-]{23}[ ]*Page[ ]*[0-9]*[-]{23}`to extract the page number from an string like `----------------------- Page 1-----------------------` it works fine using javascript regex implementation:

```
var s = "----------------------- Page 1-----------------------";
alert( s.match(/[-]{23}[ ]*Page[ ]*[0-9]*[-]{23}/) != null);
```

`match()` function returns the matched string value or `null` if pattern does not match with string. The above code show `true`

my C code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <regex.h>

//... 

regex_t reg;
regmatch_t match;
char * line = "----------------------- Page 1-----------------------";
regcomp(&reg,
          "[-]{23}[ ]*Page[ ]*[0-9]*[-]{23}",
          REG_ICASE /* Don't differentiate case */
    );

int r = regexec(&reg,
         line, /* line to match */
         1, /* size of captures */
         &match,
         0); 

if( r == 0) { printf("Match!"); } else { printf("NO match!"); }
```

the if-statement above print `NO match!` I have no idea how to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding (ORing) the `REG_EXTENDED` flag ( http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html ).

Comment: @pmg:Thanks a lot. Was worked fine. another question, it is possible to use `groups`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the regex library to recognize the full regular expression, use REG_EXTENDED in the `regcomp` flag.

> it is possible to use `groups`?

Do you mean capturing groups? Like this?

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main(void) {
  int r;
  regex_t reg;
  regmatch_t match[2];
  char *line = "----------------------- Page 1-----------------------";

  regcomp(&reg, "[-]{23}[ ]*Page[ ]*([0-9]*)[-]{23}", REG_ICASE | REG_EXTENDED);
  /*                                ^------^ capture page number */
  r = regexec(&reg, line, 2, match, 0);
  if (r == 0) {
    printf("Match!\n");
    printf("0: [%.*s]\n", match[0].rm_eo - match[0].rm_so, line + match[0].rm_so);
    printf("1: [%.*s]\n", match[1].rm_eo - match[1].rm_so, line + match[1].rm_so);
  } else {
    printf("NO match!\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, like this. Thanks very much. :)