# Match POSIX substring in C

Tags: c, regex, pattern-matching, posix

I would like to print the sub expression of match "bytes". I have simplified this example so I can debug other components of my code:

```
char *bytes="[[:print:]]*\(bytes\)";
regex_t compiled;
regmatch_t matches[2];
char currentLine[512];

fgets(currentLine, 512, ifile);
regcomp(&compiled, bytes, REG_EXTENDED);
if(regexec(&compiled, currentLine, 2, matches, 0)==0){
    printf("%s\n", bytes+matches[1].rm_so);
}
```

Where

```
currentLine= "Free Memory: 5062026704 bytes (79%)";'
```

takes place after the fgets.

The printed line I receive is an unformatted printf statement from another function - one which runs after this one. I have a few different ideas on where my problem might be(regex syntax, memory allocation, usage of regmatch_t), and I have been trying different combinations of solutions all morning but to no avail as of yet.

How can I correctly print the matched substring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different problem but using some of the sample code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656161/why-regexec-of-c-does-not-match-this-pattern-but-match-of-javascript-works) I modified this line:

```
char *bytes="[[:print:]]*\(bytes\)";
                         ^      ^
```

to this:

```
char *bytes="[[:print:]]*(bytes)";
                        ^
```

and modified the print statements as follows:

```
printf("0: [%.*s]\n", matches[0].rm_eo - matches[0].rm_so, currentLine + matches[0].rm_so);
printf("1: [%.*s]\n", matches[1].rm_eo - matches[1].rm_so, currentLine + matches[1].rm_so);
```

The format string you may not have seen before but this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932214/printf-string-variable-length-item) covers it well.

Comment: You simply want to remove the backslashes, not replace the second one with an asterisk.  As written now, it would match `byte` or `bytesssssssss`.  (Hmm, it looks like the OP tried to write a Basic Regular Expression, forgot momentarily about C's string escapes, but compiled it as an Extended RE anyway.)